# New Jupyter Notebook Tables

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, css-tables

Is there a way to use the old table layout(pre version 5.0) in Jupyter 5.0 with pandas?

The new version is very small and harder to look at than the old version (Where the cells are clearly defined)